# Is it possible to parametrize a function such as a parabola with a sin function and what would the graph look like?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, parametric

I know how to parametrize a function but the motivation of how to pick any particular way is confusing me. This example will help me out.

Start with  a simple parabola  y = x^2 in rectangular coordinates. And let x = sin (t) .  Now the y rectangular coordinate is y = (sin(t))^2.

The orientation must make a difference of course if it is truly parametrized . The only functional difference should be the speed ?  How would that affect our rectangular function in this case and what does the graph look like?   This should clear my confusion. Thank you .

Comment: "The orientation must make a difference of course if it is truly parametrized": what ??

Comment: What you get is a parametric representation of an *arc* of parabola.  For $-\pi/2 \leq t \leq \pi/2$ you get $-1\leq x \leq 1$.  For $\pi/2 \leq t \leq 3\pi/2$, you get the same arc, but "traced backwards."  For $0 \leq t \leq \pi$ you get the right half of the arc twice.  If you use $x=\sin(2t)$, $y=\sin^2(2t)$ you can shrink the interval for $t$ to $-\pi/4 \leq t \leq \pi/4$.  Is this addressing your question?

Comment: For Fabio yes...thank you ...but what is an arc of a parabola ?  is it the same graph.?   If I parametrize a line in 3D space it stays the same , correct?  is this the same principle. ?

Comment: For Yves,  when a curve is parametrized the orientation i.e direction makes a difference.  As for example if you parametrize the parabola I just spoke about in my question and use the rectangular coordinate x to be equal to -t vs. t the direction of t would be in reverse on the parabola ..or at least that's what the textbooks show....